# Laravel how to call Console command from a Database Seeder

Tags: php, laravel

I am writing some seeders for my Laravel instance's database. I'm using the [Laravel Scout TNTSearch driver](https://github.com/teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver).

```
php artisan tntsearch:import App\\MyModel
```

I want to call this command from my seeder. I've looked at the implementation, and it is complicated enough that I don't want to refactor, wait for a merged pull request, or copy-and-paste the implementation into my files.

Inside the seeder I tried:

```
$this->call('tntsearch:import', ['model' => App\User::class]);
```

But `$this` refers to the seeder, and the `call` method is expecting another seeder, not a console command.

I want to call the artisan command from inside my seeder.
Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

I ended up doing this inside the seeder:

```
exec('php artisan tntsearch:import App\\User');
```

This works but feels dirty.  Is there another easy way without using `exec()`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `Artisan` facade:

```
\Artisan::call('tntsearch:import', ['model' => App\User::class]);
```

Comment: Anyway to make this command produce output? Some import/seeding can take some time. Thank you.

Comment: If the called artisan command asks for (yes/no) answers in several questions, how do I specify them? Otherwise, the seeder simply never ends, since there's no output